# JQuery height function outputs 1

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following CSS:

```css
div#autosurf {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  position: relative;
}
div#autosurf #frames-container {
  background: #ff88ff;
  height: 79%
}
div#autosurf #info {
  height: 19%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to split the screen by 80% - 20%. This is ok and working. But the problem is when I do `$('#frames-container').height()` it outputs `1`. not `0` not `undefined` but `1`. Where could be the problem?

**EDIT 1**:
I've tried to set background color to that `frames-container` and I can see that height is bigger than `1`. what is wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle

Comment: Please update this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hv2oh5y2/

Comment: remember there are always border, padding, margin... i would say a JSFiddle would be good to have

Comment: but it's hard to immitate this specific example... I have a large application under my hands and I can't put it whole on JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:none` from `div#autosurf`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv2oh5y2/2/)

Comment: I do it like this: `$('#autosurf').slideDown();` but You've helped me to solve my problem... slideDown() takes time and I have to do my logic in setTimeout() when the slideDown is over... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try VanilaJS's $('....')[0].offsetHeight

Comment: also returns 1 anyways